# I am unable to use ggplot2 to produce any graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I try to plot graphs using ggplot, the graph does not appear on screen (as it would, say, for qplot). Instead, one of a few things happens. A blank white screen appears, a screen containing the axes labels and nothing else appears, or other various nonsensical combinations of data, axes, and labels appears.

Usually, if I restart R, I can use ggplot to make a graph, as intended, a single time. However, if I close the graph, and enter the last line of the code below, I get the result described above and the following error:

Error in UseMethod("depth"):
no applicable method for 'depth' applied to an object of class "NULL"

How can I fix this problem?

Here's some example code:

```
{library("ggplot2") #load ggplot2
data = read.table("2COLUMNDATA.txt") # the data is a 2 column, xy series
sdata = data.frame(data) #I'm just turning the data into a dataframe
scatter = ggplot(sdata, aes(x=X,y=Y)) #I want a scatterplot of the data
scatter + geom_point() # Show me the graph!}
```

If I enter:

```
qplot(x=sdata$x,y=sdata$y)
```

I get the same error. However, if I use "plot" instead of "qplot" I get no errors, and a scatter plot appears.

Currently, I am using: 
OSX 10.11.6
R: 3.3.2
XQuartz: 2.7.11

I have deleted and reinstalled R and XQuartz. The problem persists.

Comment: Questions about how to use R are off topic here. This should be on topic on [SO], so if you wait, we will try to migrate it there.

Comment: @gung I think it should be rather closed then migrated since it lacks reproducible example and in this form is unanswerable, so it would probably get closed on SO.

Comment: Your code is internally inconsistent: `qplot` references variables "x" and "y" while `ggplot` references variables "X" and "Y", thereby comprising at least four distinct variables in the data frame `sdata`, yet a comment states the data frame has only two variables!